# monit to restart more than one process at once?

Tags: monit

It seems that monit will only start a single process at a time and then wait to verify that it has started, before moving on to start the next one... even if there are lots of things to get up and running.  This can take a long time when lots of processes aren't running.

It'd probably be bad if it started everything at once too (peg out the cpu, etc), but if I could configure it to start X at once, that'd be pretty nice.

Can I configure it to start X jobs at once?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a custom script to start your list of processes, than use it as a recovery action in your Monit check, see this example from the monit documention:

`check process myproc with pidfile /var/run/myproc.pid
       if changed ppid then exec "/my/script"`